# Return the index and column name of the nth largest value in a Pandas data series

Tags: python, pandas

How can I (efficiently for a matrix much larger than the example provided) return the column name and index (or row name) of the `n`th largest or smallest value

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
matrix = df.corr()
matrix
          A         B         C         D
A  1.000000 -0.814913  0.495993 -0.880296
B -0.814913  1.000000 -0.211421  0.551441
C  0.495993 -0.211421  1.000000 -0.414037
D -0.880296  0.551441 -0.414037  1.000000
```

Then I would do something such as

```
def get_n_smallest(matrix, n):
    # can return as two variables, list, tuple, whatever...
    return row_name, col_name

get_n_smallest(matrix,0)
# would return D, A for the value -.880296
```

Comment: @JohnGalt but then that's only the lowest, not the nth lowest

Comment: True, how about `matrix.unstack().sort_values().index[n-1]` for nth smallest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series`, then remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html), [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) and get `MultiIndex` values by indexing `index`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
matrix = df.corr()
print (matrix)
          A         B         C         D
A  1.000000  0.570860 -0.558334 -0.434793
B  0.570860  1.000000 -0.358834 -0.564178
C -0.558334 -0.358834  1.000000  0.170589
D -0.434793 -0.564178  0.170589  1.000000

print (matrix.stack().drop_duplicates().sort_values())
B  D   -0.564178
A  C   -0.558334
   D   -0.434793
B  C   -0.358834
C  D    0.170589
A  B    0.570860
   A    1.000000
dtype: float64

def get_n_smallest(matrix, n):
    return matrix.stack().drop_duplicates().sort_values().index[n]

print (get_n_smallest(matrix,0))
('B', 'D')

print (get_n_smallest(matrix,1))
('A', 'C')

print (get_n_smallest(matrix,2))
('A', 'D')
```

---

```
def get_n_largest(matrix, n):
    return matrix.stack().drop_duplicates().sort_values(ascending=False).index[n]


print (get_n_largest(matrix,0))
('A', 'A')

print (get_n_largest(matrix,1))
('A', 'B')

print (get_n_largest(matrix,2))
('C', 'D')
```